# Error message is returned only for 200 or 500 error codes

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

I'm trying to return error response to the client, but it returns only when I set the status code to either 200 or 500. When I set to 304 it does not return the message. What am I missing. Please clarify

```
  res.send(304, {
            message: 'cannot update config with empty value'
        });
```

...............................................................................................................................

```
    // update configure options
exports.update = function(req, res) {
    if (req.body.items) {
       // if items exists do something        
       ....
       ....
    } else {
        // returns error message when set to 200 or 500 but does not when 304
        // ie.,response body is empty
        res.send(304, {
            message: 'cannot update config with empty value'
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you make a minimal test case? Is this using Express.js?

Comment: Simplified the code. Yes it uses ExpressJS

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
res.status(304).send({
    message: 'cannot update config with empty value'
});
```

Comment: Did not help. Same as before

Comment: in my app i use 404 status code and return a json works fine to mi

Comment: Indeed it works for 404 for me too. I wonder what's special about 304. Is there any significance to this code that I should know?

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: In w3c.org explain that -The 304 response MUST NOT contain a message-body- and indicate that the content was not modified [see here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.5)